# Not getting data from dropdown object in a childband

Tags: vbscript, automated-tests, ui-automation, infragistics, qtp

Well , I am unable to get data from a dropdown object in a cell of SwfTable. I have already tried GetCellData method to get the values from the table but it returns value in form of integers whereas the actual values displayed are strings (e.g. it returns "1" instead of "mango","2" instead of banana). This is so because the values are coming from XML file which stores integer corresponding to these values. When trying to set value for the cell(by giving integer values or string) using SetCellData,error is received for "Value does not exist in the list". I have tried to use Displaylayout or EditorControlResolved but not much examples are available as to how to use it. I have attached a screenshot of the table when inspected. The hierarchial structure of the cell which has dropdwon is Rows(1)->Childbands(0)->Rows(1)->Columns(4).Let me know what can be done.

```
    'Following line works to get value of the cell:
     ColumnValue=SwfWindow("WindowName").SwfTable("TableName").GetCellData("0;"&cstr(i),"ColumnName")
```

[image: On spying the cell from .NET windows Forms Spy]

Comment: Have you tried to use UFT's Object Spy tool?  That will at least tell you what properties UFT can recognise and that should give you a shot at figuring out what you need to do...

Comment: I have tried object spy too but it was not of much help.I have tried using sendkeys, the problem with that is whenever there are two or more values in the list with same starting word it selects the first one. We can use sendkey twice or as many times needed but even for that we need to get values from the list first. Let me know of any method or workaround that would help to get values from the list.

Comment: UFT Help has an example of setting values in an Infragistics UltraWinGrid control - perhaps that will help.  You haven't shown enough of the code you are using for me to be able to suggest any more.  I can't see what you have that isn't working, as you have only posted the code that apparently is working.